# C# Generics and Type Safety at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, type-safety

I'm not even really sure how best to phrase the question, but I'll see what I can do.

I have a goal, but I'm not sure how to, or if I even can, achieve it.

Let's say I have a type `Sport`. And then there's a `Team<Sport>` and a `Player<Sport>`. I'd like to make it such that any time I have a Team and a Player interact via methods, they can only do so if they have the same `<Sport>` type.

For instance: `Team<Sport>.AddPlayer( Player<Sport> player)` <- How can I make it so this can only be called when both `Sport`s are the same type? If I have to derive new types from `Sport`, that could work, but I was hoping to do it based on instance at runtime.

I know the compiler won't know about the instances ahead of time, so I guess I'm wondering if there's some kind of type safety magic you can do to make it so I don't have to compare the types myself every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put instances into `<>` in C#. To achieve "type safety" you need to have actual "types" called `Tennis`, `Hockey`, `Badminton` etc. Otherwise the compiler cannot distinguish between sports.

Either you check whether the types of sports are the same at runtime, or you create subclasses of `Sport`, like `Tennis`, `Badminton` and `Hockey`. Since you want type safety at compile time, you should use the latter approach.

You can do something like:

```
var tennisTeam = new Team<Tennis>();
tennisTeam.AddPlayer(new Player<Tennis>());
```

`Team` can be defined like this:

```
class Team<TSport> where TSport : Sport {
    public void AddPlayer(Player<TSport> player) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, duh, I completely blanked on that part - of course they have to be types, not instances. That does make sense though, and accomplishes what I wanted, I think. Thanks!